# Explicit formula for eigendecomposition of rank-1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (for some $n > 1$) be non-orthogonal and have all non-zero elements then $\mathbf{X} = \vec{a}\vec{b}^T$ is rank-1 and thus $\mathbf{X} = \lambda \vec{v}\vec{v}^T$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ and eigenvector $\vec{v}$,

Is there a closed-form formula for the eigenvalue and eigenvector as a function of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$?

Comment: Do you mean that $\bf X$ is a $n\times n$ matrix? I think it is usual to write the vectors as columns so you'd rather write ${\bf X}=a \,b^\top$.

Comment: Yes $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and I see your point about the possible confusion with an inner product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $ \vec{a}\vec{b}^T \vec{a} = (\vec{b}^T \vec{a}) \vec{a}$ so $\vec{a}$ is your first eigenvector. It is associated to the eigenvalue $(\vec{b}^T \vec{a}) $. There are no other eigenvalue besides 0 because your transformation is of rank one.

Comment: In fact there are $n-1$ eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue 0.

Comment: @Miguel Indeed! Edited.

Comment: @coudy if we let $\vec{a} = [2\text{ }4\text{ }9\text{ }1]^T$ and $\vec{b} = [1\text{ }8\text{ }3\text{ }4]^T$ then $\vec{a}\vec{b}^T\vec{a} = \vec{b}^T\vec{a}\vec{a}$ but $\mathbf{X} \triangleq \vec{a}\vec{b}^T \neq \lambda\vec{v}\vec{v}^T$ if $\lambda = \vec{b}^T\vec{a}$ and $\vec{v} = \vec{a}$, why is that?

Comment: There are plenty of rank one matrices that are not of the form $\lambda \vec{v} \vec{v}^T$. You just found one. For more examples, note that if $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are orthogonal, then all eigenvalues are zero hence the matrix can't be of the form $\lambda \vec{v} \vec{v}^T$.